# Why did the Aurors not Apparate to flee Grindelwald in the Lestrange Family Mausoleum?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

In a scene in *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald*, Grindelwald's followers apparated from the Lestrange Family Mausoleum after the "spread the news" command was given by Grindelwald. Grindelwald then cast a magical blue fire spell that tests the loyalty of his followers and used the flame to eliminate the Aurors. Why didn't the Aurors Apparate like Grindelwald's followers?

Comment: Someone should stay there to save paris with help of "Finite" spell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that some of them tried to apparate but the blue fire burned them.
Grindelwald's work probably.

It is visible in the 0:06 in this video:

<sub>Unfortunately the quality of the video is bad, feel free to improve if you can.</sub>

Comment: Why the -1 vote?

Answer (score 3):

## Some tried to Disapparate but couldn’t.

Some of the Aurors did try to Disapparate away from the mausoleum, but they were still caught by Grindelwald’s fire spell.

> *TINA retaliates, throwing a curse at GRINDELWALD, but the circle of fire lashes out in ever more violent spears. GRINDELWALD conducts the flames as though leading an orchestra, the Elder Wand his baton, as the forks of fire strike at AURORS attempting to Disapparate or flee.* 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald (The Original Screenplay)*</sup></sub>

Aurors did try to Disapparate - they just didn’t manage to escape.